# LINQ to sql classes LINQ to sql Objects?

Tags: visual-studio, linq

Is **LINQ to SQL Classes** and **LINQ to sql Objects** are the same thing? I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community version and their is no **LINQ to sql Classes** option and instead of that it has **LINQ to sql Objects**.
My teacher used **LINQ to sql classes** and he **added LINQ to sql classes** their is video [link](https://youtu.be/McCspgoX410?list=PLRBov8uf2SxSr11l99cFe23GuqjwYUUFp&t=627) the video is not in English.
After that he is dragging table to the `.dbml` file, but when Im trying to do the same.It isn't giving me the drag and drop facility, I think it is because I'm using Community version and I added **LINQ to sql Objects** file.
[image: Option that my teacher getting]

This is the window comes up when my teacher adds **LINQ to sql Classes** file.

[image]

[image: Option that I'm getting]

This is the window comes up when I add **LINQ to sql Objects** file and it doesn't allows dragging table over it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved.
What I did? I open the installation menu to check I've properly installed all packages and their in individual components the LINQ to sql tool wasn't checked I wonder why it wasn't checked.
But i checked and modified my installation and it is working fine now and I'm getting **LINQ to sql classes** option now instead of **LINQ to sql objects**.
But I still don't understand what was the difference between LINQ to sql classes and objects.